# How can I assign an event handler to multiply text input field /change text on click?

Tags: javascript

I have a table of input text fields.  I want to add an event handler to all of the fields so that when clicking on the cell an X fills the input value and cell.  Click again and the X value becomes an "" again. 
I have assigned the event handlers but am having trouble setting the new value on the input field.

I have tried many snippets from different places on the web and can't get the value to change in the table cell(input text field).

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', changeValue);
  }
}

function changeValue(el) {
  var el = this;
  var v = el.value;

  if (v === "") {
    v = 'X';
    console.log(v);
  } else if (v === 'X') {
    v = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">type</th>
      <th scope="col">1/4</th>
      <th scope="col">3/8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="list_group">
      <td class="cell1" data-label="type">
        <input aria-label="type" type="text" name="input_1[]" value="Fir"></td>
      <td class="cell2" data-label="1/4">
        <input aria-label="1/4" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="cell3" data-label="3/8">
        <input aria-label="3/8" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_group">
      <td class="cell1" data-label="type">
        <input aria-label="type" type="text" name="input_1[]" value="SYP"></td>
      <td class="cell2" data-label="1/4">
        <input aria-label="1/4" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="cell3" data-label="3/8">
        <input aria-label="3/8" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_group">
      <td class="cell1" data-label="type">
        <input aria-label="type" type="text" name="input_1[]" value="Marine"></td>
      <td class="cell2" data-label="1/4">
        <input aria-label="1/4" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="cell3" data-label="3/8">
        <input aria-label="3/8" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The premise is to present a large chart that a user can check the product they have or are interested in from the chart

Comment: It looks like you just need checkbox `<input type="checkbox">` instead of a `textbox`

Comment: I am using a plugin that creates the form and the plugin does not allow mixing the input types. The type row needs to be text and is dynamically populated. I want to modify the results I am getting.  I don't have a lot of choice about using the plugin at the moment

Comment: Then I guess you are using the wrong plugin. Based on your business case, the users need a control to check/un-check their choices of products. Checkbox are there for that purpose, no need to tweak textbox to do the job of a checbox.

Comment: Okay, I will look for other options to try.  It would still be nice to know what is wrong with my code as far as changing the input value though. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was close. Event handlers receive an `event` as an argument, and you can access the registered DOM element within the hander via `this`. [See here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value)

So, all you need to do is simplify your code within the `changeValue` function. Instead of `el` which implies element, use `e` to stand for event. This will help you in the future, since there are several properties on the event object that can be helpful for various purposes besides the one at present.

Next, you can both get and set the `value` of the particular `input` being clicked via `this.value`, since `this` is bound to the targeted DOM element.

The event handler then can be reduced to a simple `ternary` operation:

```
function changeValue(e) {
    this.value = this.value === "X" ? "" : "X"
}
```

The `ternary` operation checks the condition if the value equals "X" and if so, return an empty string, otherwise (meaning the value is something other than X) return "X"

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'text') {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', changeValue);
  }
}

function changeValue(e) {
    this.value = this.value === "X" ? "" : "X"
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">type</th>
      <th scope="col">1/4</th>
      <th scope="col">3/8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="list_group">
      <td class="cell1" data-label="type">
        <input aria-label="type" type="text" name="input_1[]" value="Fir"></td>
      <td class="cell2" data-label="1/4">
        <input aria-label="1/4" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="cell3" data-label="3/8">
        <input aria-label="3/8" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_group">
      <td class="cell1" data-label="type">
        <input aria-label="type" type="text" name="input_1[]" value="SYP"></td>
      <td class="cell2" data-label="1/4">
        <input aria-label="1/4" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="cell3" data-label="3/8">
        <input aria-label="3/8" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list_group">
      <td class="cell1" data-label="type">
        <input aria-label="type" type="text" name="input_1[]" value="Marine"></td>
      <td class="cell2" data-label="1/4">
        <input aria-label="1/4" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
      <td class="cell3" data-label="3/8">
        <input aria-label="3/8" type="text" name="input_1[]" value=""></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  You help to solve my problem and I learned a little bit more about js.  Thank you and this works just as I need it to.